# Problema ao inserir Imagem

Tags: bug

Estou tentando inserir imagem em minha resposta/pergunta, porém a mesma demora para encaminhar a requisição ao **imgur**, após certos minutos é retornado o erro abaixo:

```
An error occured when uploading the image
```

Verifiquei no console do browser e estou recebendo o seguinte erro:

```
Failed to load resource:  /upload/image?method=json&https=true:1
net::ERR_SPDY_PING_FAILED
```

Comment: Problema persiste?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss sim!

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que acho que o tal protocolo SPDY estar ativado (tecnologia usada no Chrome e outros projetos baseados em Chromium): https://www.chromium.org/spdy/spdy-whitepaper e o seu Chrome esta uns 3 anos desatualizados (Creio que o SPDY em `ERR_SPDY_PING_FAILED` se refira a isto), veja isto:

> https://blog.chromium.org/2016/02/transitioning-from-spdy-to-http2.html

Tanto o SPDY quanto o NPN foram removidos no Chrome 51, hoje, 28/05/2019 estamos na versão 74

Solução? Atualize o Chrome

Comment: Não tem nem um mês que eu formatei o meu computador e instalei o chrome, está na última versão. Este problema começou a ocorrer somente há uma semana. Eu não posso afirmar isto, pois não sei se é só comigo, mas talvez esteja tendo algum problema de requisição com o imgur.

Comment: @THIAGODEBONIS usa addons? Usa proxy na rede? Seu provedor de internet é proprio da cidade, destes menos conhecidos?

Comment: A configuração está limpa, e é a mesma quando a inserção das imagens funcionavam.

Comment: Pode parecer a mesma, mas controle sobre proxies e provedores creio que não tenha nada haver com a sua instalação do windows, a não ser que o driver de rede seja generico e você não atulizou ele